# How prevent Laravel from stripping empty arrays

Tags: laravel

As title says, how to prevent Laravel from removing empty array in input json? Example: Given client request

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/test",
    data: {
        populatedArray: ["Fine, as long as it has >0 elements"],
        emptyArray: [], // This property will not be available!
        tasks: {
            fooTask: {
                empty: [],
                nullObject: null,
                regular: "It should also work for nested"
            }
        }   
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
});
```

And Controller

```
public function test(Request $request) {        
    Log::info(json_encode($request->populatedArray));
    Log::info(json_encode($request->emptyArray));
}
```

I get the following log messages:

```
[2018-01-30 12:30:01] local.INFO: ["Fine, as long as it has >0 elements"]  
[2018-01-30 12:30:01] local.INFO: null
```

I would like the second row to produce [] but it is not present in the $request object??

Answer (score 1):

Before sending it to server, package data as a string

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/stimpack/test/",
    data: { 
        myValue: "all good",
        populatedArray: ["Fine, as long as it has >0 elements"],
        emptyArray: [], // This property will not be available!,
        tasks: JSON.stringify({
            fooTask: {
                empty: [],
                nullObject: null,
                regular: "Hi all"
            }
        }) 
    },
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Next, in your controller unpack the string to object like this

```
$inputAsObject = json_decode($request->tasks);
```

Logging it will reveal also the empty arrays

```
Log::info(json_encode($inputAsObject));
```

Another benefit is you dont have to worry about Laravel treating everything as associative arrays. That means you can do this:

```
Log::info(json_encode($inputAsObject->fooTask->empty));
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a second param as a default value to `get()` method

```
 $arr = [];

 Log::info(json_encode($request->get('emptyArray',$arr)));
```

Comment: Thanks, though I was a bit unclear. It also need to work for nested (unknown) parameters like "tasks.fooTask.empty" in updated example. Any thought on that?